# How to call new ViewTemplate in AvalonDock?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, avalondock

I am able to create new ViewTemplate:

```
class SearchViewModel : ToolViewModel//I make SearchViewmodel to inherit from ToolViewModel
{
    public DataTemplate SearchViewTemplate
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public override System.Windows.DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, System.Windows.DependencyObject container)
    {
        //The code omitted for brevity...
    }
}
```

and SearchViewTemplate:

```
<avalonDock:DockingManager.LayoutItemTemplateSelector>
  <local:PanesTemplateSelector>
     <local:PanesTemplateSelector.FileViewTemplate>
         ...//The code omitted for brevity...
     </local:PanesTemplateSelector.FileViewTemplate>
  <local:PanesTemplateSelector.FileStatsViewTemplate>
         ...//The code omitted for brevity...
  </local:PanesTemplateSelector.FileStatsViewTemplate>
     <local:PanesTemplateSelector.SearchViewTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <TextBlock Text="Hello World!:)"/>
        </DataTemplate>
     </local:PanesTemplateSelector.SearchViewTemplate>
  </local:PanesTemplateSelector>
```

Code to show SearchViewTemplate Workspace.cs:

```
    SearchViewModel _searchViewModel = null;
    public SearchViewModel SearchHelper
    {
        get
        {
            if (_searchViewModel == null)
                _searchViewModel = new SearchViewModel();

            return _searchViewModel;
        }
    }
```

XAML to call template:

```
<MenuItem Header="Tools">
   <MenuItem Header="Properties" IsChecked="{Binding FileStats.IsVisible, Mode=TwoWay}" IsCheckable="True"/>
   <MenuItem Header="Search Window" IsChecked="{Binding SearchHelper.IsVisible, Mode=TwoWay}" IsCheckable="True"/>
</MenuItem>
```

However, TextBlock with Text="Hello World!:)" is not shown.
How to show newly created ViewTemplate?